# Распечатывается счет наполовину

Tags: ubuntu

Счет в pdf распечатывает почему-то наполовину, а win7 - все в порядке, не подскажете, в чем дело может быть? И как исправить?

Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снят. Установил Adobe Reader и все хорошо.